# Why is the phrase "abstraction" used in radical reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals

Often, I see the phrase "abstraction" used to describe certain radical reactions. Why is this specific term "abstraction" used in the case of radicals? This may be more of a chemical history / linguistics question.

To give more context, the term substitution is used in some reactions, and it describes how the molecules change, an atom substituted for another. Is abstraction being used in this same sense to describe the process of the reaction, or just used to differentiate these reactions since they involve radicals?

Comment: It is rather a question  for [dictionary search](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abstraction) :  *4/ the act of taking away or separating; withdrawal: The sensation of cold is due to the abstraction of heat from our bodies.*

Comment: In $\ce{CH4 + Cl^. ->CH3^. + HCl}$, there is the abstraction of  $\ce{H}$ atom from $\ce{CH4}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fancy history behind abstraction, it is simply the Latin derivative. One can look up the etymology in any decent dictionary and see that

> classical Latin *abstract*-, past participial stem of *abstrahere* to drag
> away, to appropriate, take away, to set free, to separate, to deduct,
> subtract, to exclude, to turn aside, divert, in post-classical Latin
> also to summarize (from the subscribed version of the Oxford English Dictionary).

When we say the radical abstracts a proton from a certain compound, it simply means that the radical took away (dragged away) a proton from that neutral or even charged compound. Although, I do not like this anthropomorphism at atomic or molecular scale. This "abstraction" can be classically seen in gas phase reactions of alkanes with chlorine in the presence of light.